# How can I do this query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

this is the controller method

```
public function ajaxLoad()
{
    $data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id DESC");
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', $data, true);
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
}
```

and this is the js that invokes ajax

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; 
$(document).scroll(function(){ 

currentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(); 

if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop ) 
{
    var result = currentScrollTop % 100;
    if(result == 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax/load",
          type: "POST",
          success: function(res){

          $("#content").html(res);

          }
        });
    }
}
else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) 
{
    var result = currentScrollTop % 100;
    if(result == 0)
    {
        $("#content").text("Вверх запрос " + result);
    }
}

tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop; 
})
```

the problem i that i can't get the part of a page with the query that goes in the content and then json_encode to transfer to javascript, if i remove the

```
 $data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id DESC");
```

and change this to

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', null, true);
```

thus without the $data object its ok.

then its comes empty, but i need the database rows to display in the content

how can i solve this problem??

and the echo $data; - its the only way to transfer the data to js??, i tried return $data;, but that doesn't work :(

and also the main problem is that the PHP generates the page with the foreach function that generates records by loop, but if i put one of those records with ajax will the variables inside that partial become values of the database query??, or i need to set the values with js??

i am confused about that, sorry if i am wrong, can you help me???

so this is how looks the page generated by php by when the pages loads:

```
<? $i = 1 ?>
<? foreach($query->result() as $q): ?>



<?
$milliseconds = $q->end;
//echo $dd;
//echo time();
 /*
$year = date('y', $t);
$month = date('m', $t);
$day = date('d', $t);
$hour = date('h', $t);
$minute = date('i', $t);
$second = date('s', $t);
*/
$d = new Datecalc;
$begin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$end = date($q->end);
#$date = $d->dateDiff($begin , $end);
//$begin = strtotime($begin);
//$end = strtotime($q->end);
$d->dateDiff($begin, $end);
//echo $d->day;

$desc = substr($q->desc, 0, 225);
if(strlen($desc) > 180)
{
    $desc = $desc."...";
}
 ?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $milliseconds ?>" id="milliseconds_<?= $q->id ?>" />
<div class="item" id="item_<?= $q->id ?>">
        <? if(!empty($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin'): ?>
        <div class="admin_delete">
        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>delete/<?= $q->id ?>"><?= img('css/img/admin_delete.png'); ?></a>
        </div>

        <? endif; ?>
    <div class="desc">
    <span class="discount">Скидка <?= $q->discount ?>%</span>
    <span class="desc"><?= $desc ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item_pic">
    <? $attr = array('src' => $q->image,
    'id' => 'item_pic',
    'class' => 'item_pic') ?>
    <?= img($attr) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_3">
        <ul class="menu_3">
            <li class="timer">
            <? $attr = array('src' => 'css/img/time.png',
            'class' => 'time') ?>
            <?= img($attr) ?>
            <span id="days_<?= $q->id?>"><?= $d->day ?></span>д.
            <span  id="hours_<?= $q->id?>"><?= $d->hour ?></span> :
            <span  id="minutes_<?= $q->id?>"><?= $d->min ?></span> :
            <span  id="seconds_<?= $q->id?>"><?= $d->sec ?></span>
            </li>
            <li class="price">
            <?= $q->price ?>с.
            </li>
            <li class="buy">
            <div class="small">
            99
            </div>
            <a href="<?= base_url() ?>buy/<?= $q->id ?>">
            <?= img('css/img/kupit.png') ?>
            </li>
            <li class="item_arrow">
            <?= img('css/img/item_arrow.png') ?>
            <? if($i % 2 == 0): ?>
                <ul class="submenu2">
                <? else: ?>
                <ul class="submenu2">
            <? endif; ?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>show/<?= $q->id ?>">
                    Подробнее
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>how" style="color: #fef102;">Как это работает</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-bottom: none;">
                    <a href="">Рассказать друзьям</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-bottom: none;">
                    <a href=""><?= img('css/img/namba.png') ?></a>
                    <a href=""><?= img('css/img/mail_ru.png') ?></a>
                    <a href=""><?= img('css/img/odnoklassniki.png') ?></a>
                    <a href=""><?= img('css/img/vkontakte.png') ?></a>
                    <a href=""><?= img('css/img/facebook.png') ?></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
<? $i++; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

i dont know how to put the records by ajax separately gradualy when the user scrolls down

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting these two lines

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id DESC");
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', $data, true);
```

as

```
$db_data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id DESC");
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('item', $db_data, true);
```

As it is, you are sending, as part of the JSON output, the query response from the DB (in the $data array).  Then replace the last two lines with

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: please consider upvoting the answer if it's useful :)

Comment: But i after that i make $("#content").html(result) - the result of that query is something like this what can i do? {"content":"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
\n\t
\n\t\u0421\u043a\u0438\u0434\u043a\u0430 50%<\/span>\n\tOpisanie<\/span>\n\t<\/div>\n\t
\n\t\t<\/div>\n\t
\n\t\t
\n\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t5<\/span>\u0434.\n\t\t\t54<\/span> :\n\t\t\t32<\/span> :\n\t\t\t06<\/span>\n\t\t\t<\/li>\n\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t3000\u0441.\n\t\t\t<\/li>\n\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t99\n\t\t\t<\/div>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/li>\n\t\t\t
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t </br > what can change this output?

Comment: Looking again at your code example, I'm a bit confused.  Is the view JSON or HTML?  The last bit of code you present is presumably the 'item' view, and is HTML etc.  In which case, why do you call json_encode() on its result?  It looks like you don't need to encode as JSON.

Comment: Ohhh of course, yes is html, thanks for that advice, wait a minute i have a few more questions , dont go far :)